Is it bad practice to return on every iteration of a map loop?
I like how this map works but I have a suspition that it might be bad practice to use return on every iteration of a loop
Is this a bad practice?
Thank you
const array = [
  ["Header 1", "Header 2"],
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
];

const mappedArray = array.map((row, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    return row;
  } else {
    return row.map((value) => value * 2);
  }
});

I have tried searching for an answer to this but found nothing

with map, you kinda want to do that, unless you want undefined entries in the mapped output

I downvoted because the question isn't really helpful. In the title and description you ask about loops, but in the code you have Array.prototype.map. That's not the same.

It is by definition how map works

@JaromandaX On the other hand, I think checking whether the index is 0 on every iteration seems inefficient. Wonder if there's a better way other than a for loop offset by 1.

Do note that array[0] is === mappedArray[0]... in that they refer to the same object. If array[0][1] is changed, mappedArray[0][1] will also be changed. This is different from other rows.

This is fine, the way the array.map function works is by calling your function to see how to the map the values.
The main concern would be if you're calling the variable often, if not I wouldn't worry about it

Thank you. I tried to select this as an answer, but I don't have enough reps to do it

You actually need to return on every iteration of the Array.map method. There's a 'sort of' equivalent Array.forEach method that works exactly the same, except it doesn't automatically return an array. If you don't think you need to return an array, but instead you want to do something with each item in the array, the forEach method will save a little bit of memory, but if you actually have a use case that needs the map function over the forEach function, returning is required. The app won't break if you don't, but you'll be assigning variables or storing things in memory that you're not actually using.
